# Is it possible to give a condition to enable or disable python with statement?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, with-statement

I am trying to make a custom training code for the TensorFlow Keras model.

As we need to separate `train_step` (which updates the model weights) and `test_step` (which only makes the inference), I wonder if we can make a single function that can work for both.

My idea is to write something like this.

```
def _train_or_evaluate(self, inputs, gt1, gt2, is_training=False):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape1 'if is_training': # Enable or disable the with statement by condition
        model1_output = self.model1(inputs)
        model1_loss = self.loss_obj(gt1, model1_output)

    inputs2 = self.process_output(model1_output)

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape2 'if is_training': # Enable or disable the with statement by condition
        model2_output = self.model2(inputs2)
        model2_loss = self.loss_obj2(gt2, model2_output)

    if is_training:
        model1_gradients = tape1.gradient(model1_loss, self.model1.trainable_variables)
        self.optimizer1.apply_gradients(model1_gradients, self.model1.trainable_variables)

        model2_gradients = tape2.gradient(model2_loss, self.model2.trainable_variables)
        self.optimizer2.apply_gradients(model2_gradients, self.model2.trainable_variables)

    return model1_loss, model2_loss

def train_step(self, inputs):
    inputs = inputs, (gt1, gt2)
    return self._train_or_evaluate(inputs, gt1, gt2, True)

def test_step(self, inputs):
    inputs = inputs, (gt1, gt2)
    return self._train_or_evaluate(inputs, gt1, gt2, False)
```

Is there any way to give a condition to enable or disable the `with` statement while keeping the block running? So when the condition is False, the block is still running similarly as without the `with` statement.

Such that:

When `self._train_or_evaluate(inputs, gt1, gt2, True)` it is equivalent as:

```
def _train(self, inputs, gt1, gt2):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape1:
        model1_output = self.model1(inputs)
        model1_loss = self.loss_obj(gt1, model1_output)

    inputs2 = self.process_output(model1_output)

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape2:
        model2_output = self.model2(inputs2)
        model2_loss = self.loss_obj2(gt2, model2_output)

    model1_gradients = tape1.gradient(model1_loss, self.model1.trainable_variables)
    self.optimizer1.apply_gradients(model1_gradients, self.model1.trainable_variables)

    model2_gradients = tape2.gradient(model2_loss, self.model2.trainable_variables)
    self.optimizer2.apply_gradients(model2_gradients, self.model2.trainable_variables)

    return model1_loss, model2_loss
```

And when `self._train_or_evaluate(inputs, gt1, gt2, False)` it is equivalent as:

```
def _evaluate(self, inputs, gt1, gt2):
    model1_output = self.model1(inputs)
    model1_loss = self.loss_obj(gt1, model1_output)

    inputs2 = self.process_output(model1_output)

    model2_output = self.model2(inputs2)
    model2_loss = self.loss_obj2(gt2, model2_output)

    return model1_loss, model2_loss
```

Thank you.

Comment: You want to disable the creation of `tape2`? Or the management of it? Or the entire contents of the block? Basically, which lines are completely disabled?

Comment: @ShadowRanger given that `tape1` and `tape2` don't appear to be used anywhere in the code, I'm not sure it makes any difference.  I'm quite confused by this question.

Comment: @MarkRansom: My assumption is that creating them changes the behavior of the contained code in some way (much like `decimal` module contexts controlled by `with` statements), but I might be giving too much credit here.

Comment: no, not even writting a class with a very clever (or convoluted) `__enter__` module it is possible to skip the execution of a with block. Just use an `if` block, nesting the ẁith` statement within it (or the other way around)

Comment: @MarkRansom @ShadowRange: Yes, right. When the code is written inside the `tf.GradientTape()` block, it will keep track of the gradients flow of the variables. And it will take more computational resources. It is used when `tape.gradient()` is called. So I am wondering if we can effectively enable or disable the `with` statement effectively given the condition in python. I updated the question to give clearer examples of my expectation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this through clever use of [`contextlib.ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack) to separate the `with` and the creation of the managed object, so the managed object can be created and managed conditionally. For the first conditional `with`, you'd replace it with:

```
with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
    if is_training:
        tape1 = stack.enter_context(tf.GradientTape())
    model1_output = self.model1(inputs)
    model1_loss = self.loss_obj(gt1, model1_output)
```

Omit the `tape1 =` if you don't actually need it bound to something named `tape1` (since you don't, and can't, use `tape1` thanks to being conditionally defined, it's probably unnecessary).

When `is_training` is falsy, the `ExitStack` is basically a no-op; it's created and torn down, and since it's managing *nothing*, no cleanup is performed. When `is_training` is truthy, the `GradientTape` instance is created and immediately registered with `ExitStack`, so when the `with` exits, it's cleaned up normally.

If you want to get a little nuts, you can use `ExitStack` as a building block for conditional `with` creation (it's actually documented as being intended to function as such a building block):

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def conditional_ctx(condition, callable, *args, **kwargs):
    with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
        yield stack.enter_context(callable(*args, **kwargs)) if condition else None
```

which, once defined, lets you implement your original code with:

```
with conditional_ctx(is_training, tf.GradientTape) as tape1:
    model1_output = self.model1(inputs)
    model1_loss = self.loss_obj(gt1, model1_output)
```

For just one or two uses, it's not that big a savings, but if you're doing this in many places, it saves some work.

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in the comment above, no matter how one does customize the `__enter__` metho of a class, which is the one called by the `with` statement, it is not possible for the `with` block itself to be skipped.

However, it simply nesting an extra `if` block is not desirable (or nesting the `with` within an `if`, for that matter), it is possible to fully emulate a `with` block, by using `try/finally` - and then you can use an `if` block *instead* of an `with`. It will still take an extra indentation level, though, due to both an `if` and a `try/finally` block being needed.

```
def _train_or_evaluate(self, inputs, gt1, gt2, is_training=False):
    if is_training:
        tape1 = (cm:=tf.GradientTape()).__enter__()
    try:
        model1_output = self.model1(inputs)
        model1_loss = self.loss_obj(gt1, model1_output)
    finally:
        if is_training:
            cm.__exit__(*sys.exc_info())
    ...
    # second with block and rest of the function
```

(note that I use the walrus operator ( `:=`) to keep a reference to the instance from which the `with` statement would call the `__.enter__` and `__exit__` methods. Ordinarily, in a `with` block one won't need to care about this)

Comment: Your ordering is a little off here; `cm` must be created outside the `try`, so if `tf.GradientTape()` raises an exception, it doesn't try to access `cm` in the `finally` (I forget whether `__enter__` should be called within the `try` when simulating a `with` precisely; I don't *think* so, but I'm too tired to look it up). Also, you presumably meant `cm.__exit__`, not `cm.exit`.

Comment: to be precise `__enter__`   should be outside as well  (an exception inside `__enter__` does not go through `__exit__` in the same instance) .- I've just edited it - thanks.

Comment: Anyway, higher level code should use `ExitStack` like in your answer - I will leave this published as it describes the "under the hood" of a `with` and can help people getting here to understand things, and it might be less things to wrap-the-head around in simpler scripts.